# Create object using operator (bpy.types.Operator)

Tags: python, scripting, objects, add-on, operator

I faced the situation when I have to create an object using an operator. However, documentation says that operators "can’t pass data such as objects, meshes or materials to operate on (operators use the context instead)" (https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_63_7/info_gotcha.html)
So, I didn't get how to use this "context" to create an object.

The situation is that when I create my object with operator, it doesen't appear in scene. When I try to add it to a scene, there is an error, like `RuntimeError: Error: Object 'Sphere' is already in scene 'Scene'`. `bpy.data.objects` has anything exept for my new object.

So, here's my code:

```
class UpdateButton(bpy.types.Operator):
bl_idname = "update.button"
bl_label = "Update"

def getList(self, list):
    self.names = list.keys()
    for name in names:
        Node().create(name)

def updateObjects(self):
    for name in names:
        Node().get(name).moveTo(list[name])

def execute(self, context):
    Node().create("node1")

    return{'FINISHED'}
```

So, you see, I am to create my objects with `getList` function, but here I simply call Node().create() straight in order to work this problem out.

Class `Node()` defines operations I can do with my objects:

```
class Node():
material = makeMaterial('Blue', (0,0,1), (0.5,0.5,0), 1)    

def get(self, name):
    try:
        self.ob = bpy.data.objects[name]

    except:
        print("Node: Object " + name + " is not found")
    finally:
        return self

def create(self, name, origin = cursor):
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_uv_sphere_add(location = origin)
    ob = bpy.context.object
    ob.data.materials.append(self.material)
    ob.name = name
    ob.show_name = True
    return ob

def moveTo(self, pos, delta_frame):
    print(self.ob)
    self.ob.select = True
    self.ob.keyframe_insert(data_path = 'location', frame = scene.frame_current)
    delta_path = [pos[i] - self.ob.location[i] for i in range(3)]
    print('delta_path = {0}'.format(delta_path))
    bpy.ops.transform.translate(value = delta_path)
    self.ob.keyframe_insert(data_path = 'location', frame = scene.frame_current + delta_frame)
    self.ob.select = False

def remove(self):
    context.scene.objects.unlink(self.ob)
    bpy.data.objects.remove(self.ob)
```

Well, how can I create objects with operator and what exactly I have to change in my code. I noticed that this part of code worsk properly despite the problem:

```
delta_path = [pos[i] - self.ob.location[i] for i in range(3)]
print('delta_path = {0}'.format(delta_path))
```

I think it means that our new object with all its data still exists, we simply need to make it appear somehow.

So, the question is: how can I create objects with operator and what exactly I have to change in my code?

UPD:

I forgot to add that this operator is being used inside the other operator this way:

```
class Menu(bpy.types.Operator) :      
bl_idname = "visualizer.menu"  
bl_label = "Menu Panel"  
bl_options = {"REGISTER", "UNDO"}                                           

print(bpy.data.objects)
def gen_list():
    if bpy.data.objects is None:
        return [("NULL", "NULL", "It seems data hasn't been received yet")]
    else:
        return [(ob.name, ob.name, ob.type) for ob in bpy.data.objects]

DropDownList = bpy.props.EnumProperty(items=gen_list(), name = "Object", description = "Choose object here")                  

xCoord = FloatProperty(
    name = "X", 
    description = "X coordinate of the object")
yCoord = FloatProperty(
    name = "Y", 
    description = "Y coordinate of the object")
zCoord = FloatProperty(
    name = "Z", 
    description = "Z coordinate of the object")

def execute(self, context):
    for ob in bpy.data.objects:
        print(ob)
    bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
    obj = bpy.data.objects[self.DropDownList]
    obj.select = True

    self.xCoord = obj.location.x
    self.yCoord = obj.location.y
    self.zCoord = obj.location.z

    return {"FINISHED"}

def draw(self, context):
    layout = self.layout
    layout.prop(self, "DropDownList")

    col = layout.column()
    col.label(text="Attributes:")

    col.prop(self, "xCoord")
    col.prop(self, "yCoord")
    col.prop(self, "zCoord")
    layout.operator("update.button")
```

Calling `update.button` operator the second time crashes program.